# Cannot import .ics calendar file into Samsung Calendar

Tags: calendar, import

I have an .ics calendar file which I cannot import into my Samsung Calendar.

If I click on it, it opens and I can see all entries. I can then click "Save all to calendar", and it says "Importing...". But after a few seconds, I get a popup saying

> Calendar has stopped
>
> Open app again

The same .ics file imports fine into Thunderbird on a PC, and a friend could import it from an email into his iPhone.

My phone is a Samsung Galaxy A6 with Android 8.0.0. The Calendar app is version 4.4.09.1.

Comment: Try clearing the cache & storage of app, reboot and then import... May work

Comment: @beeshyams: I did reboot and tried again, but it made no difference. Not sure how I can clear the app's cache. Don't see anything like that in Calendar's menu.

Comment: From settings go to apps, you may have to turn on "Show system apps" or something like that from the (usually) top right 3 buttons//Find calendar app and delete storage (you will lose all existing calendar entries) so make sure you have a backup and also turn off wifi and data so that your local backup isn't interrupted by calendar sync

Comment: If this also doesn't work after deleting app storage, access your calendar app on the web and import the ics file. Then enable data and sync calendar (search in your settings, I am not familiar with Samsung)